# Can I use concatentation in a Verilog lvalue? (Possible Modelsim compiler bug?)

Tags: verilog, modelsim

### Problem

I've been having trouble at work with the line:

```
{ s_b, s_a[0] } <= 2'd3;
```

In Modelsim 10.2c it appears to assign to b, but not to a.

Does anyone know why this does not work - and whether it is bad style in Verilog?

### Full test code

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module modelsim_top_tb;
`define CLK_PERIOD 20
reg         clkin = 1'b0;
reg         aresetn = 1'b0;
always begin : clkgen
    #(`CLK_PERIOD/2) clkin <= ~clkin;
end
always @(posedge clkin) begin: rstgen
    #(`CLK_PERIOD*10) aresetn <= 1'b1;
end
initial begin
  #(`CLK_PERIOD*20)
  $stop();
end            
test1 u_test1
(
    .clk(clkin),
    .aresetn(aresetn)
);
endmodule

module test1(
  input wire clk,
  input wire aresetn);

reg [7:0] s_a;
reg s_b;

always @(posedge clk or negedge aresetn) begin
    if (!aresetn) begin
        s_a <= 8'h00;
        s_b <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        //{s_a[0]} <= 1'd1;  // This works
        {s_b,s_a[0]} <= 2'd3; // This does not work, a is displayed as 0
        $display("a=%d b=%d",s_a,s_b);
    end
end

endmodule
```

### Steps to reproduce

I have been testing this code with the commands:

```
vlib work
vmap work
vlog testcase.v
vsim -c -do "run -all; quit -f" modelsim_top_tb
```

In Modelsim 10.2c it prints out a value of 0 for s_a on every clock cycle.

However, if I run the same code in EDA playground, all the simulators (including Modelsim 10.1d) correctly print out a value of 1 for s_a after the first clock cycle has passed.

Comment: I tried it on 10.2c and it works for me. BTW I suggest using  `$strobe` instead of `$display` to see the results at the end of the time step. I tried it on a number of other versions. 10.2d is not released yet.

Comment: @dave_59 Sorry, you are quite right, the 10.2d was a typo.  EDA playground actually says it uses 10.1d.  Thanks for trying it out, it is odd that your modelsim works better than mine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use concatenation in a Verilog lvalue.  It looks like good coding style. It works for me on 2 other simulators (vcs and incisive); I don't have access to modelsim. I think it is a bug in Modelsim 10.2c.

Comment: I concur. I also ran it vcs, incisive, and the simulators on EDA playground and got the correct results, value `1`. Good coding style too. You might want to report the bug to Mentor Graphics.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying it on different simulators, looks like it is an isolated issue with my setup somehow.

Comment: I ran your model in modelsim student edition 10.2c, and you are right. 
On the command window it shows that the value for a is always 0, and also in the waveforms.
I also ran it on vcs, and it works. I agree with Greg and Toolic that is a bug in modelsim

Comment: @DOS - many thanks - I was beginning to think I must have made a stupid mistake somehow as no-one could replicate the issue!  We are on a proper commercial license so I guess I should try and contact support.  Thanks again.

Comment: Could the bug be caused by an incorrect assignment that it's done two lines before? `s_a <= 8'h00;` should read `s_a <= 7'h00;` as `s_a` is a 7 bit register.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix  Thanks - I've corrected it in the question.  However, the bug remains the same.  I'll raise a ticket on Monday on Supportnet.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that maybe it's that assignment what confused the buggy Modelsim interpreter, and that the bug itself manifested in the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this to Mentor as support request 2599370923 and they have fixed the bug in version 10.3 beta 2 (to be released soon).